# TranslateAnimation hidden view before the end on animation

Tags: android

I'm using TranslateAnimation to show a fragment on another view to the bottom at the top. The problem is that the back view is hidden before the animation is ending, I need see the view until the animation is finished.

This is my code:

```
buttonLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        hideFragment();
    }
});
WatchDetails.fourthLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (WatchDetails.showFrag == false) {
            showFragment();
        }

    }
});

public void showFragment() {
    System.out.println("showFragment");
    mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 800, 0);
    mAnimation.setDuration(500);
    mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    mAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);
    mAnimation.setZAdjustment(-1);

    mAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        }
    });

    WatchDetails.frag.startAnimation(mAnimation);

    firstLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    WatchDetails.frag.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    WatchDetails.showFrag = true;
}

public void hideFragment() {
    System.out.println("hideFragment");
    mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 720);
    mAnimation.setDuration(500);
    mAnimation.setFillBefore(true);
    mAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);

    firstLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    secondLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    thirdLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fifthLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    WatchDetails.frag.startAnimation(mAnimation);

    getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
    origButtonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    WatchDetails.showFrag = false;
}
```